# How can I get a persistent counter in a Matlab function without an `isempty` hack?

Tags: matlab

I would like to add a counter to a function so it knows how many times it has been called.

Here is what I am currently using.

```
function Foo ()
persistent counter;
if (isempty(counter))
     counter = 0
end 

counter = counter + 1
end
```

Line 3-5 looks like a hack.

How can I directly initialize counter to 0 without having it reset or using isempty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merlin, `isempty(marker)` should be `isempty(counter)` but I'm sure that's what you meant. The code you have is what the matlab documentation recommends if you look [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/persistent.html) and [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/defining-and-initializing-persistent-variables.html). Additionally, this is also what Loren [uses](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/03/29/understanding-persistence/) as well. So what you have is correct (sorry if this answer is not satisfying).